# Operation is not allowed when the object is closed when using the "Insert Into"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sqlconnection

I hope you can help me on this. I'm getting an error `Operation is not allowed when the object is closed` when trying to execute the `Insert into` query but working in `Select`. I'm using vb.net btw (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010).

I open my database in module using this statement:

```
On Error GoTo Connprob

        DARHS_Connect = False

        conEmail = New ADODB.Connection
        conEmail.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=" + Server + ";Database=DatabaseName;Uid=" & User& ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
        conEmail.Open()

        DARHS_Connect = True
Exit Function
```

and then here's the code that works with no errors:

```
rsX = New ADODB.Recordset
        EmQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN1 = '" & Recipient & "' AND COLUMN2 = '1'"
        rsX.Open(EmQuery, conEmail, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly)

        If Not rsX.EOF Then
            Do While Not rsX.EOF

                EmQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE(COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) VALUES"
                EmQuery = EmQuery & "('" & RQuote(rsX.Fields.Item("EMAIL").Value) & "',"
                EmQuery = EmQuery & "'" & Message & "',"
                EmQuery = EmQuery & "'" & ServerDate & "'"
                EmQuery = EmQuery & "'PCO')"
                conEmail.Execute(EmQuery)

                rsX.MoveNext()
            Loop

        End If
```

And here's the code that gives me the error:

```
EmQuery = "INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4) VALUES"
        EmQuery = EmQuery & "('" & Recipient & "',"
        EmQuery = EmQuery & "'" & Message & "',"
        EmQuery = EmQuery & "'" & ServerDate & "',"
        EmQuery = EmQuery & "'PCO')"
        conEmail.Execute(EmQuery)
```

Hope you guys can help me since this is a blocker on my project.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really shouldn't be using ADODB in VB.NET to begin with. If this is a company project and someone else makes those decisions then you're over a barrel but, if you are making the decisions, I suggest that you make the decision to use VB.NET properly and use ADO.NET for data access.

Comment: What's the point of `If Not rsX.EOF Then` if it's followed by `Do While Not rsX.EOF`? The latter will automatically jump to the end of the loop if `rsX.EOF` is `True` anyway so the `If` statement is redundant.

Comment: As for the issue, I don't touch ADODB so I'm not going into this in any detail but it seems fairly obvious that, when that code is executed, `conMail` is not open. The obvious next step is to debug your code and to place breakpoints where `conMail` is opened and closed to see what state it is in and why it's not what you expect. For all we know, you have two variables with that same name and are only opening one of them.